# APNG gets out of sync after second page refresh

Tags: javascript, animation, browser, png, apng

I have an app with an animated UI realised via APNG images.

Each block has 2 APNG images and one PNG one:

1. Appearing (APNG)
2. PingPong (APNG)
3. Static (PNG)

I need to play the second animation right after the first one is finished and only make visible the PNG image after a touch event. I've done it via `setTimeout` but, unfortunately, after second page refresh a browser completely ignores some animations, some of them start jittering, some disable in an inappropriate moment.

How can I fix the problem?
And can I catch the moment when APNG animation has finished? Do APNG images emit any events?

To check the problem, open [the app](https://mammoth-freezing-surgeon.glitch.me) on mobile device and scan [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JIeM.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't have any built-in support for treating APNGs as anything other than an image: there is no way to determine when an APNG has started or stopped playing. You could probably fix the issue by just converting the APNGs to an actual video file format, and embedding the images with `<video>` instead, since [that has an API for controlling playback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). Alas, it doesn't seem that any browsers support treating APNGs as video so you'll need to convert it to another video format, such as WebM.

If you are *really* committed to not converting your APNGs to a video file format, you could work around the limitation in browsers by using a library such as [pngjs](https://github.com/arian/pngjs) to decode the APNG, extracting [the `fdAT` chunks](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification#.60fdAT.60:_The_Frame_Data_Chunk), and then manually animating through those extracted frames (each frame in an APNG is itself a (non-animated) PNG).